# Turn whole Python project into one standalone .exe file including ALL dependecies

Tags: python, windows, exe

I have a Python project with 2 Python files and 2 imported modules (pynput and requests). So my problem is when I ran this command which I found on the web:

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import "pynput requests"  main.py

After I launch the .exe file I get an error: pynput module not found.

I have also made a requirements.txt, I dont know wether that helps.

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import "pynput requests"  main.py

I ran this command and the build was successful, but I guess it skipped the modules or something.

The other StackOveflow questions didnt mention being completely standalone.

Comment: Did you use a virtual environment or did you check directly over the base python?

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi yes i have a venv

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import=pynput --hidden-import=requests main.py 
 Daniel try this once

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi still doesnt work :( it works fine as .py

Comment: can you share the full error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi and i get like a standard windows window

Comment: I am in the chat you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
pip install virtualenv
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import=pynput --hiddenimport=requests main.py

Comment: After 40 mins of banging our head to get this solution

Answer (score 0):

I found this [guide](https://blog.finxter.com/python-to-exe-with-all-dependencies/) and it talk about using pyinstaller with the `--hidden-import` flag to list which dependencies are being included in your exe file. I hope this help you